# Pip install/upgrade error, will not install or upgrade anything, odd traceback

Tags: python, import, openssl, dependencies, pip

`Python Version=2.6.6`

Ok, so this one has me stumped.

First off, here is the traceback for when I try to install something.  In this case I ran: `pip install requests`
as root. NOTE: I am aware this is pip version `7.0.3`.  The same traceback appears with the latest version of pip.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 291, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 705, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 317, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 304, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 439, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 244, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/index.py", line 486, in find_requirement
    all_versions = self._find_all_versions(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/index.py", line 404, in _find_all_versions
    index_locations = self._get_index_urls_locations(project_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/index.py", line 378, in _get_index_urls_locations
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/index.py", line 810, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/index.py", line 920, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/download.py", line 373, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 279, in ssl_wrap_socket
    cnx.set_tlsext_host_name(server_hostname)
AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'set_tlsext_host_name'
```

I then uninstalled pip using `pip uninstall pip`and confirmed that the egg and binary files were removed.  Then I reinstalled it using `easy_install pip` but no luck.  I also tried this again but with the latest version of pip and version `7.0.3`.  Same thing.

Also, installing `get-pip.py` gives this traceback, which is oddly similar:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 291, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 705, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 317, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 304, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 387, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 348, in _check_skip_installed
    finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, self.upgrade)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 486, in find_requirement
    all_versions = self._find_all_versions(req.name)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 404, in _find_all_versions
    index_locations = self._get_index_urls_locations(project_name)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 378, in _get_index_urls_locations
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 810, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 920, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 373, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/tmp/tmp0rv6P1/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 279, in ssl_wrap_socket
    cnx.set_tlsext_host_name(server_hostname)
AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'set_tlsext_host_name'
```

What really has me confused is the last 4 lines of the traceback.  After analyzing the traceback I dove into the pip egg.

Obviously from the traceback, the error is coming from the `ssl_wrap_socket` function, which is called in `connection.py`.  The traceback says that `ssl_wrap_socket` called is defined in `{urlib3_path}/contrib/pyopenssl.py`, but, upon looking at lines `45-50` of `connection.py`:

```
# connection.py
     from .util.ssl_ import (
         resolve_cert_reqs,
         resolve_ssl_version,
         ssl_wrap_socket,
         assert_fingerprint,
     )
```

`ssl_wrap_socket` should be importing from `{urllib3_path}/util/ssl_.py` which does not contain the offending line of code, but according to the traceback that is not what is happening.

I have no idea what is going but assume this is some subtly about python I am unaware of.  If anyone has any clue please let me know.

Edit: New development!

Upon stumbling onto [this bit of the requests code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/a57c87a459d51c5b17d20285109e901b8aa95752/requests/__init__.py#L54) from github it appears that the requests library actually injects `pyopenssl` into the urllib3 library which explains the traceback.  However I am still unsure of how to fix this.

Edit2: Solution!

Turns out the urllib3 library was being injected with the wrong `pyopenssl` !  After I found out that requests was injecting `pyopenssl` into the `urllib3` library I checked out `pyopenssl.py` and found this function:

```
def inject_into_urllib3():
    'Monkey-patch urllib3 with PyOpenSSL-backed SSL-support.'

    connection.ssl_wrap_socket = ssl_wrap_socket
    util.HAS_SNI = HAS_SNI
```

`ssl_wrap_socket` is defined in `pyopenssl.py` and relies on `OpenSSL.SSL`.

I hopped on over to `pyOpenSSL-0.15.1-py2.6.egg` in the `site-packages` folder and just to be sure checked the version, which was `0.15.1`.  After some pondering I opened up the interpreter and ran

```
>>> import OpenSSL.SSL as ssl
>>> ssl.__file__
```

Which told me I had an OpenSSL directory in `lib64/python2.6/site-packages` that was being referenced rather than the `OpenSSL` directory in the `pyOpenSSL` egg, and it was only version `0.10`!  which of course what was causing the original error to be thrown.  After removing that directory Pip seems to be running without issue.

Comment: Have you tried install pip with `curl -s https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python` ?

Comment: I did.  I added the traceback from that as well.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 12.04 or older as your operating system?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Answer (score 0):

```
easy_install http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.12.tar.gz
```

Executing above line may fix your problem.

There's an [upstream bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+bug/845445) for CentOS 5.6 related to this issue.
And also there's a [workaround patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+bug/845445/comments/9) for fixing it. If above method doesn't work, you can try this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I ended up finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the easy_install code line by devunt and it didnt work. It denied access to a bunch of conflicted python 2.7 files. I basically had the same problem with pip. I'm on Mac OSX and got stuck on pip 7.0.3 and to get things like scikit, numpy and scipy, I need to uprade to 7.1.0 apparently. Im on Python 2.7.6 and after following the error messages when I tried to download mysql-python, I was brought to an error message like shown and followed it to source which was an error message for an 'unstable system due to the SSL security around https' (ie Python 2.7.6). My error message was this:

```
You are using pip version 7.0.3, however version 7.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3 py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90:              InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents        urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections        to fail. For more information, see   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting pip
Using cached pip-7.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 7.0.3
Uninstalling pip-7.0.3:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 297, in run
root=options.root_path,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 616, in install
requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 721, in uninstall
paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 126, in remove
renames(path, new_path)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 314, in renames
shutil.move(old, new)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
rmtree(src)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-        7.0.3-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/dependency_links.txt'
```

So, as I understand it, this error is driven by an incompatability bundled with Mac's OS X on Python 2.7.6. As brew on Mac was what I used to upgade python in the past, I used "brew update" and when brew updated, I went and upgraded python with "brew install --upgrade python" and when complete I checked my versions which are as follows:

```
John-Mulhalls-MacBook-Pro:Python_DataBase_Project jmulhall$ brew --version
0.9.5
John-Mulhalls-MacBook-Pro:Python_DataBase_Project jmulhall$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
John-Mulhalls-MacBook-Pro:Python_DataBase_Project jmulhall$ pip --version
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
John-Mulhalls-MacBook-Pro:Python_DataBase_Project jmulhall$
```

Learnt lesson for me to solve this error was to upgrade python to 2.7.9 (I read about a bug in prior versions affecting Pip) or above. Pip will bundle with Python 2.7.10 as Pip 7.1.0. I successfully installed 'brew install mysql-python'
and will get around to installing bumpy, scipy and scikit when get back to data science, decision trees and python. Hope this helps bro!!..